# Find a path in a matrix based on cells value (R)

Tags: r, matrix, vector

I have a calculation given binary matrix 0 or 1. These matrix always show when I plot it that the cells having value '1' create a path as illustrate below as example. The path is not always from one border to another one.

I would like to create a vector or a line following this path as illustrated below (the red line is just a plot as example to illustrate what I mean when I mention create a vector or line).

The objective is to use this line to perform calculation as: shortest distance from a specific cell to this line etc.

```
setwd("C:/Users/Desktop/test/")
mat <- read.csv("test.csv",  header = TRUE)
mat <- as.matrix(mat)
mat
      X0 X0.1 X0.2 X0.3 X1 X1.1 X1.2 X1.3 X1.4 X0.4 X0.5
 [1,]  0    0    0    0  1    1    1    1    0    0    0
 [2,]  0    0    0    0  1    1    0    0    0    0    0
 [3,]  0    0    0    0  1    1    0    0    0    0    0
 [4,]  0    0    0    0  1    1    0    0    0    0    0
 [5,]  0    0    0    0  1    1    0    0    0    0    0
 [6,]  0    0    0    0  1    0    0    0    0    0    0
 [7,]  0    0    0    0  1    0    0    0    0    0    0
 [8,]  0    0    0    1  1    0    0    0    0    0    0
 [9,]  0    0    0    1  1    0    0    0    0    0    0
[10,]  0    0    0    1  1    0    0    0    0    0    0
[11,]  0    0    1    1  0    0    0    0    0    0    0
[12,]  0    0    1    1  0    0    0    0    0    0    0
[13,]  0    0    1    1  0    0    0    0    0    0    0
[14,]  0    0    1    1  0    0    0    0    0    0    0
[15,]  0    0    0    1  0    0    0    0    0    0    0
[16,]  0    0    0    1  0    0    0    0    0    0    0
[17,]  0    0    0    1  0    1    0    0    0    0    0
[18,]  0    0    0    1  1    0    0    0    0    0    0
[19,]  0    0    0    1  1    0    0    0    0    0    0
[20,]  0    0    0    1  1    0    0    0    0    0    0
[21,]  0    0    0    1  1    0    0    0    0    0    0
[22,]  0    0    0    1  1    0    0    0    0    0    0
[23,]  0    0    0    1  1    0    0    0    0    0    0
[24,]  0    0    0    0  1    0    0    0    0    0    0
[25,]  0    0    0    0  1    1    0    0    0    0    0
[26,]  0    0    0    1  1    1    1    0    0    0    0
[27,]  0    0    0    0  1    1    1    1    1    0    0
[28,]  0    0    0    0  0    0    1    1    1    0    0
```

[image]

Comment: Provide reproducible example data: `dput(mat)`. Also, what have you tried?

Comment: what does this red line represent? How do you calculate distance from cell to red line?

Comment: The red line would represent what I would like to have. Find the path and simplify it by a simple line that I could use to calculate distance, etc

Answer (score 1):

I used the package segmented as display below:

```
##clean Global Environment
rm(list=ls())
gc(reset=TRUE)
plot.new()
memory.size(TRUE)
##############################################################
##############################################################
##############################################################
library(data.table)
library(igraph)
##############################################################
##############################################################
##############################################################
setwd("C:/Users/Desktop/test/")
mat <- read.csv("test.csv",  header = TRUE)
mat <- as.matrix(mat)

#dimension matrix
v <- dim(mat)[1]
h <- dim(mat)[2]

df <- data.frame()

ind <- 0

for(j in 1:v){
  for(k in 1:h){
    if (mat[j,k] == 1){
      ind <- ind+1
      df[ind, 1:3] <- data.frame(j, k, mat[j,k])
    }
  }
}

library(segmented)
set.seed(12)
xx <- df$j
yy <- df$k
zz <- df$mat.j..k.

dati <- data.frame(x = xx, y = yy)
out.lm <- lm(y ~ x, data = dati)
o <- segmented(out.lm, seg.Z = ~x, psi = list(x = c(2,4)),
               control = seg.control(display = FALSE))
dat2 = data.frame(x = xx, y = broken.line(o)$fit)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dati, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line(data = dat2, color = 'blue')
```

[image]